# Fetching data from two tables using a specific criteria

Tags: php

What I am doing is: Fetching data to show the products to user, so that he/she can rate products. Which is working fine using below query.

```
$query = "  SELECT      table_products.product_name, 
                        table_products.product_expiry, 
                        table_users.name,
                        table_users.email

            FROM table_products
            INNER JOIN table_users ON table_users.user_id = table_products.user_id 
            ORDER BY table_users.id DESC";
```

Now what I want to ask is: How to show only those products that the user hasn't rated yet. Once a user rates a product, that product should not be fetched by the query for that user again.

I've 3 tables

```
table_users (user_id, name, email)

table_products (product id_, user_id, product_name, product_expiry)

table_rating (rating_id, user_id, product_id, rating)
```

and I want to fetch data from 2 tables

```
table_users, table_products
```

data to be fetched

```
table_users.name, 
table_users.email, 
table_products.product_name, 
table_products.product_expiry
```

How to set query for this task for a specific `user_id`?

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: Just to be clear, you question is about SQL and not about PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can join the ratings table and count the number of ratings then check it in the where clause, something like this (**untested**):

```
$query = "SELECT
table_products.product_name, 
table_products.product_expiry, 
table_users.name,
table_users.email,
count(table_rating.id) as ratings

FROM table_products
INNER JOIN table_users ON table_users.user_id = table_products.user_id 
left join table_rating ON table_rating.product_id = table_products.id

where ratings = 0
ORDER BY table_users.id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, You need join table, group by and use having clause, please refer to the image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT      table_products.product_name, 
                        table_products.product_expiry, 
                        table_users.name,
                        table_users.email

            FROM table_products
            INNER JOIN table_users ON table_users.user_id = table_products.user_id 
            LEFT JOIN table_rating on table_products.product_id=table_rating.product_id
            WHERE table_rating.product_id IS NULL
            ORDER BY table_users.id DESC
```

Comment: hi. using your code, i am getting 1) rated products added by other users (which should not be fetched) and 2) unrated products of his own and other users. but i need only unrated products regardless added by his own or other users

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      
table_products.product_name, 
table_products.product_expiry, 
table_users.name,
table_users.email

FROM table_products
INNER JOIN table_users ON table_users.user_id = table_products.user_id

LEFT JOIN table_rating ON table_products.user_id = table_rating.user_id 
AND table_products.product_id = table_rating.product_id

WHERE table_rating.product_id IS NULL

ORDER BY table_users.user_id DESC
```

Comment: hi @Leandro your ans is much close.

Comment: but there is an issue that products added by other users are also visible to current_user after rating. just those products are skipping which are posted by the same user who is rating.

Comment: actually i want to skip both rated products(added by the same user who is rating and other users). we have user_id of that user who is rating. can we apply it to get the desired output